# Bootstrap Page Header Title Link to Tumblr

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have just installed a bootstrap theme and want to link one of the page titles to an external site. This is the section of the code that I can see where the page is. Can anybody help me bounce this title to an external URL?

```
<li class=""><a href="#releaseNotes" data-toggle="tab">Release Notes</a></li>
```

Comment: Could we see the code?

Comment: the code is there, he just didn't put it in properly. I have a pending edit, but if you look, it's there.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li class=""><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
```

Bonus: to open in a new tab, use `target="_blank"`

```
<li class=""><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks @pennstatephil I posted the code you put there. have a look at it: http://www.getfive59.com/ I cant get the blog link to bounce out

Comment: looking at your source, there are 2 `http`s in your href, as well as a stray `</li>` at the end of the list items

Comment: I removed the stray </li> i dont see the second href

Comment: <ul id="features-tab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
                       
                     
                        <li class=""><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="http://http://getfive59.tumblr.com/">Blog</a></li>